# Measuring 400V three phase large consumer power

Tags: power, motor, current-measurement, three-phase

I need to measure the power consumption of a large (11kW) electrical motor during various stages of operation. I have a few interlinked questions:

1. I'm interested in the power the operator of that motor would be charged for. I'm not sure if that is real, apparent, both?
2. Can I use a clamp on ammeter and measure the current of just one phase, or do I need to measure all three?
3. Given I cannot measure the 400V supply, is it reasonable to trust that it is in fact 400V, or what voltage do I need to use for a three phase power supply? Or do I need to hire a qualified electrician (Health ans Safety...)?

A certain scientific rigour for this is required as I intend to model the power consumption of the motor, but with a linearized system, to be presented at a civil engineering conference. (So accurate, but I and the audience are not interested in the details too much)

I intend to use a clamp on ammeter, preferably with logging (PC hookup), capability. Any recommendations (I'm UK based)?

Comment: Don't assume a nominal 400V supply is actually exactly 400V.  More likely, it's 400V ±10% or perhaps ±6%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It depend on contract, usualy only real power is charged, the instrumen shall count real, reactive, apparent.
2. 3 current transformers and 3 volatages is the exact measuring, but you can use one current and one voltage with asumption that network and motor are balanced (that would be rathere an estimation than measuring).
3. Any power meter for rated voltage for your country is ok, let's say 400VAC nominal.

Industrial power meters, there are a lot of them. I can just give you one example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggDtJWUbkJ4

Comment: Thanks, I've since found power meters, that should be up for the job. eg: http://www.test-meter.co.uk/spc-portable-mini-energy-profile-logger-spcmini/

Answer (score 0):

Speaking on a conference, it would be much entertainment if you can show the signal(s) acting on a wire. A meter cannot provide you with that ability, but a stand alone **merging unit** (aka SAMU, AMU, MU), like [this](http://www.alstom.com/grid/products-and-services/Substation-automation-system/protection-relays/Analogue-merging-unit/) or [this](http://www.vizimax.com/en/products-services/merging-units), can.

Having current(s) and voltage(s) signals represented as sampled values over real time (this is what an MU does), you may reconstruct any derivatives, such as instant/averaged power, harmonics/spectra, etc.

Comparing with an MU, a meter is very inertial instrument not intended to facing transitional and non-periodic signals, it is oriented to only slowly changing, periodic signals near around mains frequency (generally, 50/60 Hz ± 5 Hz).

Also, if your motor is powered thru an inverter, a typical meter will lie.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll look into using a merging unit. What do you mean, the meter will lie? Not measure the reactive or complex power?

Comment: Typically, a meter is calibrated at the mains frequency (50 or 60 Hz depending on the country it is for) and has the measuring error bounded (by design, to be cheaper) in a very narrow frequency range, for example, mains ± 5 Hz. Out of this band, the measuring error is unpredictable and may be any.

Comment: When you connect a motor directly to the network, the mains "rotates" it directly, i.e. on "self", therefore there is one power frequency --- the mains frequency and a meter before the motor will work in its specified freq range with known measuring error.

Comment: When you connect a motor to the network indirectly, using an inverter, the mains supplies the inverter, and the inverter --- in its turn --- forms a signal to "rotate" the motor. Typically, an inverter does not apply a mains freq signal when it need to start up the motor, it generates a signal with growing up frequency, from 0 Hz to the frequency you set (mains or other). Therefore, a meter between the inverter and the motor will work in the unspecified freq range and its measuring error will unknown.

Comment: Also, you need to remember that a meter gets the power to work from the network (lines) it measures on, too. Its internal power supply is oriented to work on the mains frequency and its behavior is unpredictable outside this range.

Comment: My additional advice to you: if you will connect to the power network directly, it is better (and presentably) to use a (synchro-) phasor measurement unit (PMU) to show the i's and v's as vectors on complex plane and see the angles between i's and v's; if you will use an inverter, it is better (and much informative) to use a merging unit (MU).

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. The motor is driven by a variable frequency drive. This is the datasheet for a very similar one: http://www.unopomp.com/Resimler/SiteIcerik/MGE.pdf ,
But in conclusion, I need to measure the voltage during operation as well, specifically with a merging unit if possible. Which means I need to go through a lot of health an safety paper work...

Comment: As i see, MGE motors have "built-in" inverter (= variable frequency drive). The circuits between the "built-in" inverter and the motor itself are not accessible from outside. Therefore you can see only v's and i's going from the power network to the inverter, but not from the inverter to the motor itself.

Comment: In the datasheet, p. 12, i/o module: _An analogue output enabling reading of ... current frequency, intermediate circuit power or motor current._ May be this helps you better.